# custom tag select .attr returns undefined

Tags: jquery, spring-mvc, tags

I have created a custom tag and now I am trying to get the value of the custom attribute, I have tried many ways and for some reason the alert returns undefind...Thanks guys.

```
<goladmin:select    cssClass="shortSelect"
            path="textType" 
            items="${textTypeList}"
            itemValue="id" 
            itemLabel="description"
            widgetType="widget"                             
            onchange="true"                                                  
            multiple="false" />
```

JavaScript

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    //call to get the widget type
    getWidgetType();    

    //On select dropdown change
    $('#textType').change(function(){   

      var wt = $('#textType').val();
        alert("widgetType=" + wt);


        //call to get the widget type
        //getWidgetType();
    });
}); 


function getWidgetType(){

    var value = $('#textType').val();
    //set hidden textTypeWidget to the selected widget
    $('#textTypeWidget').val(value);

    //get the widget type value from the hidden field
    var widgetType =  $('#textTypeWidget').val();   

    // show and hide the editor based on the widget type
    if(widgetType == "CKEDITOR") {              
        $('#ckEditorEditor').show();
        $('#textAreaEditor').hide();

    }else{
        $('#ckEditorEditor').hide();
        $('#textAreaEditor').show();
    }

}
```

generated HTML

```
<select id="textType" name="textType" class="shortSelect" onchange="true"><option value="1" selected="selected"></option><option value="2">button label</option><option value="3">title</option><option value="4">error message</option><option value="5">link text</option><option value="6">url</option><option value="7">label</option><option value="8">text</option><option value="9">table title</option><option value="10">help text</option><option value="11">question text</option><option value="12">answer text</option><option value="13">question help text</option><option value="14">glossary</option><option value="15">information mesage</option><option value="16">confirmation message</option><option value="17">system message</option></select>
```

Generated HTML when setting the itemValue to widget....

```
<select id="textType" name="textType" class="shortSelect" onchange="true"><option value="TEXTAREA" selected="selected"></option><option value="TEXTAREA">button label</option><option value="CKEDITOR">title</option><option value="TEXTAREA">error message</option><option value="TEXTAREA">link text</option><option value="TEXTAREA">url</option><option value="TEXTAREA">label</option><option value="TEXTAREA">text</option><option value="TEXTAREA">table title</option><option value="CKEDITOR">help text</option><option value="CKEDITOR">question text</option><option value="CKEDITOR">answer text</option><option value="TEXTAREA">question help text</option><option value="CKEDITOR">glossary</option><option value="CKEDITOR">information mesage</option><option value="CKEDITOR">confirmation message</option><option value="CKEDITOR">system message</option></select>
```

Comment: can you share the generated html?

Comment: sorry, i dont get it...who or what is #textTypeWidget ?

Comment: textTypeWidget  would be the type of editor I will be displaying to user based on the textType... I know what my problem is, I need ti add a new attribute to the custom tag for the textTypeWidget in order for me to make this happen.The generate HTML should basically look like this <option value="5" widgetType="TEXTAREA">link text</option>

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
var wt = $('.shortSelect').attr('widgetType');
```

instead of:

```
var wt = $('#textType').attr('widgetType');
```

Comment: @Korda Your generated HTML doesn't have any `widgetType="widget"`?

Comment: Yah and I am not sure why :( LOL no wonder it was returning undefined :( i did var wt = $('#textType').val(); and i get the value... and if I change the itemValue to widget I do get the widget type... not sure whats goingon now..

Comment: these guys are saying if it doesnt get generated it should still work.. questions-20889213

Answer (score 0):

the '#' is id selector, you need to set id in your element:

```
<goladmin:select   
        id="textType" 
        cssClass="shortSelect"
        path="textType" 
        items="${textTypeList}"
        itemValue="id" 
        itemLabel="description"
        widgetType="widget"                             
        onchange="true"                                                  
        multiple="false" />

 var wt = $('#textType').attr('widgetType');
 alert("widgetType=" + wt);
```

Comment: umm howcome $('#textType').change(function(){  works without the id? I did try adding the id and still the same :(

Comment: LOL trust me, i have alert("changing"); and everytime i change the dropdown i get this alert :)

Comment: maybe when the page load , the html hasn't created the code yet, but it get the change event, not sure

Comment: the javascript is inside a $(document).ready(function(){}); ?